# Is their an inbuilt function from the csv class in python which automaticly assigns your data a primary key?

Tags: python, csv

I was wondering whether the python class "csv" had an inbuilt function which allowed for the automatic assignment of a primary key.

For Example:

```
Lemons,Sugar
Pears,Grapes
```

Should then have a primary key automatically assigned to them:

```
1,Lemons,Sugar
2,Pears,Grapes
```

And if the program where to be restarted and new data entered, the primary key should then continue.

```
1,Lemons,Sugar
2,Pears,Grapes
3,Rasins,Salt
```

Surely there's an inbuilt function/operation such as assign_primary_key()
from the python csv class?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `pandas` module to read `csv` files where an index is assigned to each row as you wanted, e.g:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_file')

In [1]:

df

Out[1]:

    1       2
0   Lemons  Sugar
1   Pears   Grapes
```

If you want to add the index as a column, you can do the following:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

You can also reassign column names like this:

```
df.columns = ['id','item1','item2']

In [4]:

df

Out[4]:

    id  item1   item2
0   0   Lemons  Sugar
1   1   Pears   Grapes
```

Answer (score 0):

> Surely there's an inbuilt function/operation such as assign_primary_key() from the python csv class?

No, there is not. That's not the purpose of `csv`. The module simply converts lines of text into tuples. The whole concept of primary keys (or keys of any sort) is unrelated to CSV files. If you want keys for your records, you need something more database-like.